# Can not use .next() from $this in jquery each function

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to determine of an elements height is more then 55. If that is the case the wrapping div shall collapse to 55px and a "Read-more" link should appear.

The problem is that the dom navigator .next() and .hide() is not working inside my each function. I am getting the height of the element that is ok, i am logging them to the console and get differnt value that is ok. But when I use a IF statment to hide the .read-more link from the elements that are to small it is not working.

Here is my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eKDUe/ , I am totally lost. I Hope someone can help!

```
readMore.prev('p').each(function( index ) {

var deg = $(this).height();
console.log(deg);
if (deg < 55 ){
  var  as = $(this);
  var as2 = as.next();
console.log(as2);      
}
});


readMore.on('click', function(){
 $this = $(this);
var current = $this.prev();
console.log(current);
  if(current.height() < 55){

      current.css('height', 'auto');
     $this.html('Dölj');
   }else{
    current.css('height', '53px');
    $this.html('Läs mer');
   }
});
```

Comment: what is the `readMore`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somethin glike

```
readMore = $('.read-more').hide()
readMore.filter(function(){
    return $(this).prev().height() > 55;
}).show()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EKZfa/)

Comment: That together with some modifications makes the code work! Thank you so much for the help! I added the 'children' navigator so it gets to the P element. Thank you again!

   `readMore = $('.read-more').hide()`
   ` readMore.filter(function(){`
    ` return $(this).prev().children().height() > 55;`
   ` }).show() `